# I get a 404 when I try to read my messages

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I changed my email address in the settings page. Now when I try to read my messages I get the error: "Oh no! We can't find the page you're looking for."

[image]

Comment: Can you try again? I might have fixed it but I need you to double-check. Thanks!

Comment: My old messages are still displaying the same error but new messages are coming through OK.

Comment: Please try one more time. If it's still not working, I'll submit a bug ticket to the dev team.

Comment: It works! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

When you changed your email, it broke the link between your account and it's messages. We've fixed the link and you should be good to go.